# Draw on Google Maps and filter results according to that drawn area | Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-drawable

I fetch lat-longs from an API and display them on the Google map. Now, I am offering a drawing tool which lets the user draw on the map and apply this to get the pins in just that specific drawn area by the user.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you!

Screen 1: Shows all the pins based on the lat long. 
[Pins on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp1ed.jpg)

Screen 2: Draw Feature that will let the user draw. [User Draw Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieche.jpg)

Screen 3: This screen will fetch the pins in just the area selected in Screen 2 by the user

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Achieve what? Draw on the map or get the pins, it's not clear.

Comment: I fetch all the pins and place them on the map. Now, I let the user draw on the map and apply the draw feature. 

Once the draw circle is applied, it only shows the pins in that specific region drawn by the user. 

Please check the screens which I just updated.

Comment: Change the question to: How to only fetch and show the google map markers inside an specific area drawn by a user?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the positions or the shape of the drawing.
2. Draw that as an polygon shape on the map, then filter out the markers or fetch only the markers inside that shape. [You can follow this guide on Android Dev](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes), And here is some more information [on markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker).

Comment: The challenge is that the shape can be anything, it is just a random finger drag that the user performs. 

This is the best resource that I could get on what I want to achieve but the code is buggy and shows pins even for the area apart from the user drawn one. 

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, ether you debug your code and find the issue or you develop a completely new way of doing this or you simplify and use whatever out-of-the-box-solution provided for shapes, like rectangles, circles, triangles, on Android Developer Portal.